# Adding a record in Datagridview Row in Vb.net

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, datagridview

Hello I have Datagridview in my vb.net form and i want to display the data from the MySQL table to the Datagridview (Dgv) of Vb.net but the problem is when i update or delete an record in Dgv the current record that i fetch is adding more display of the current record. I write this code like this because I'm going to add more function on it, I know i can do this using MySqlDataAdapter and DataSet then fill the datagridview of this code but i use this to add more function, for now how can i update/delete an record without adding more rows that i currently fetch. or doubling the row's

```
Dim SQL as String = "Select * from employee"
Dim cmd as MySqlCommand = new MySqlCommad(SQL, connection)
Dim reader as MysqlDataReader = cmd.executeReader()
Dim empId, empName, empAddress as String
with reader.Read
    empId = reader("empId")
    empName = reader("name")
    empAddress = reader("address")

Dim row() As String
row = new String() {empId, empName, empAddress}
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
End While
reader.close()
cmd.close()
```

I know the problem is in Rows.Add

Added:
Currently the function of this is to display the data and when event or button was click this Sub will be called again. with out adding more display.

Comment: If you load your `emplpyee` table to a DataTable, you dont have to add rows to the DGV, you can bind the table to it and it will show everything automagically.  To add a new emp, add a new DataRow

Comment: Currently i don't use the DataTable because I'm going to filter some of the data example of it, i the EmpAddress is From US i not going to show in datagrid but i will pass it on variable for future use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim SQL as String = "Select * from employee"
Dim cmd as MySqlCommand = new MySqlCommad(SQL, connection)
Dim reader as MysqlDataReader = cmd.executeReader()
Dim empId, empName, empAddress as String

'before adding new row in datagridview add this code
DataGridView1.Rows.clear();
with reader.Read
    empId = reader("empId")
    empName = reader("name")
    empAddress = reader("address")
```

so that it will remove the old value of the row and then add the new value in the database

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.  You can easily select from sql server to datagridview, change data, and pass change from datagridview to sql server.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmdBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim changes As DataSet
    Dim sql As String
    Dim i As Int32

    Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        connetionString = "Data Source='your_server';Initial Catalog='your_database';Trusted_Connection=True;"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        sql = "Select * from Product"
        Try
            connection.Open()
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Sql, connection)
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'NOTE:  for this code to work, there must be a PK on the Table
        Try
            cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
            changes = ds.GetChanges()
            If changes IsNot Nothing Then
                adapter.Update(changes)
            End If
            MsgBox("Changes Done")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```